# Translating contextual filter nid value

Tags: nodes, views, i18n-l10n

On a multilingual site, the function named `language_negotiation_get_switch_links($type, $path)` looks up the content translation and enables user to switch to parallel content if available.
What if the path comes from Views with contextual filter being the node ID? Say, in English it'd be `en/news/197` but in German `de/nachrichten/198`. Drupal/Views tend to leave the contextual filter untouched and produces invalid criss-cross paths such as `de/news/197`. There seems to be no way to translated the value into one that belongs to a given translation set.

Is there? Or maybe I'm approaching the problem in a wrong way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key was using two functions: `drupal_get_normal_path()` and `i18n_get_path_translations()`. Inside `hook_language_switch_links_alter()` you can modify the href attribute of each language switcher.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing [hook_language_switch_links_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!language.api.php/function/hook_language_switch_links_alter/7) is definitely the way to go.  Here is the code along with two (2) helper functions, assuming there are display variants for each language.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_language_switch_links_alter().
 *
 * This is a workaround for Path Translation not supporting Views' contextual filters.
 * Alter the language switcher to switch between path/to/[term] and different
 * paths for different languages.
 */
function mymodule_language_switch_links_alter(array &$links, $type, $path) {

  // Load the current view if there is one.
  $view = views_get_page_view();

  // Act only if we're looking at the view in question.
  if (($type == "language_content") && isset($view) && ($view->name == 'myview')) {

    // Skip situations where there's no argument.  This is handled by Path Translatoon.
    if (isset($view->args[0]) && ($view->args[0] != mymodule_get_myview_view_all_term($view))) {

      // Iterate across all language links.
      $language_active = $GLOBALS['language']->language;
      $displays = mymodule_get_myview_view_language_displays();
      foreach ($links as $language_current => &$link) {

        // Skip the active language.
        if ($language_current == $language_active) {
          continue;
        }

        // Set the path for the current language.
        $path = $view->display[$displays[$language_current]]->display_options['path'];
        $link['href'] = strtok($path, '/') . '/' . $view->args[0];
      }
      // Break the foreach reference.
      unset($link);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Returns the list of displays for the view in question, keyed by language.
 *
 * @return array
 *   The list of displays.
 */
function mymodule_get_myview_view_language_displays() {
  return array(
    'en' => 'page_myview_en',
    'fr' => 'page_myview_fr',
  );
}

/**
 * Get the language-specific term representing all items.
 *
 * @param view $view
 *   The previously loaded view in question.  Optional.
 * @return string
 *   The term.  If there's no translation in the current language, "all" is used.
 */
function mymodule_get_myview_view_all_term($view = NULL) {

  // Load the view if it wasn't provided.
  $view = (is_null($view) ? views_get_view('myview') : $view);

  // Get the current language and the display names for each defined language.
  $language = $GLOBALS['language']->language;
  $displays = mymodule_get_myview_view_language_displays();

  // Return the language's "all" term, or the default if there isn't one.
  if (isset($view->display[$displays[$language]]->display_options['arguments']['tid']['exception']['value'])) {
    return $view->display[$displays[$language]]->display_options['arguments']['tid']['exception']['value'];
  }
  else {
    return 'all';
  }
}
```

Note that this doesn't handle the translation of the term itself within the path, only the part of the path leading up to it.  For now, that will always be in the default language. This is the separate issue [Views contextual filter validation: Support ET-translated taxonomy term name](https://www.drupal.org/node/2378991).